# Searching for a book about a werewolf who was a priest

Tags: story-identification, horror

#### Key Plot points

What I remember is that he was under some sort of blood lust and went on a rampage in some city I can't recall and his brother is a vampire and his dad is something powerful which I also can't remember.

I do remember his dad had some sort of weird hard to pronounce name. He was greatly feared and on some sort of council and his vampire son's wife called him Ry.

I also remember the werewolf bit a librarian from that town who had a daughter and that's who he ended up with.

#### Chronology and other relevant info

I read it close to 10 years ago.

Comment: You used marvel comics tag for some reason? Can you explain why? Was this story a comic book published by Marvel?

Comment: Although not a book, it shares many plot elements as the Underworld film series. Maybe you read the novelization?

Comment: Stephen King's *Silver Bullet* (The movie) had a werewolf priest. I didn't read the book. No father's father was mentioned in the film. Thus, I  have no actual answer.

Comment: Aegon - i'm not even too sure what i was doing, sorry about that.

Comment: it keeps telling me to add an existing post and it keeps choosing one automatically